# POST запрос по url

Tags: android, http, post

Ребят такой вопрос. Необходимо выполнить post запрос по адресу http://url.domen/part/data.php (адрес написал не действительный) и через запрос отсылаем в переменную data определенный номер.Сервер по идее должен дать ответ в виде спец. кода.
вот сервис отвечающий за это

```
public class NetworkIntentServise extends IntentService {

public NetworkIntentServise(String name) {
    super(name);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String number = intent.getStringExtra("phone");
    String result = "";
    String response = "";
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost http = new HttpPost("http://url.domen/part/data.php");
    List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", number));
    try {
        http.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        response = (String) httpclient.execute(http, new BasicResponseHandler());
    } catch (IOException i) {
        result = i.toString();
    }

    Toast.makeText(EnterPhoneActivity.getContext(),response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

}

Я так понимаю строка 
`response = (String) httpclient.execute(http, new BasicResponseHandler()); и возвращает мне этот ответ?

в итоге я получаю такую ошибку в этой же строке.Вот полный лог

```
  Process: com.example.icoper.testappjob, PID: 24084
                                                                           android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                               at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
                                                                               at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
                                                                               at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
                                                                               at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
                                                                               at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
                                                                               at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
                                                                               at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:658)
                                                                               at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:632)
                                                                               at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:621)
                                                                               at com.example.icoper.testappjob.NetworkIntentServise.onHandleIntent(NetworkIntentServise.java:39)
                                                                               at com.example.icoper.testappjob.EnterPhoneActivity.getUserCode(EnterPhoneActivity.java:135)
                                                                               at com.example.icoper.testappjob.EnterPhoneActivity.onClick(EnterPhoneActivity.java:127)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4789)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19881)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5307)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Comment: У вас почему-то onHandleIntent выполняется в главном потоке, а в нём нельзя запросы в сеть делать с API>14. Покажите как вы стартуете сервис.

Comment: вот так `new NetworkIntentServise("IntentServise")
                .onHandleIntent(new Intent().putExtra("phone",number));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы полностью неправильно используете сервис. Сервис не должен напрямую управляться вами. Он должен управляться системой. Вам нужно лишь слать ему некоторые сообщения, на которые он будет реагировать. Вы же строкой

> new NetworkIntentServise("IntentServise").onHandleIntent(new Intent().putExtra("phone",number));

Создали просто экземпляр класса и вызвали его метод. При чём из главного потока. Так сервис вообще не запустился и весь его смысл потерян.

Вам надо действовать так:

```
context.startService(new Intent(context, NetworkIntentServise.class).putExtra("phone",number));
```

Этот код говорит системе что надо запустить сервис. После чего сервис будет системой запущен в отдельном потоке, вызовется метод `onHandleIntent` выполнится ваш запрос, после чего система прибьёт сервис.

Comment: ошибка пропала, но ничего не происходит. Понял что не добавил этот сервис в манифест, но при добавлении таким способом
 <service android:name=".NetworkIntentServise"></service>
студия говорит мне о том что " has no default constructor" хотя он то есьь?

Comment: случайно тогда не весь комментарий отправил.

Comment: @ДмитрийСамойлов, default constructor - это конструктор без аргументов. В вашем случае примерно такое надо добавить: `public NetworkIntentServise(){super("justSomeString");}`

Comment: да,только что нашел в документации что он должен быть with no argument . спасибо.